# Create a list of vectors representing integers between the nth values of two equal length vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, concatenation

I want to produce a list of unequal vectors, that represent the integers between the *n*th values of two existing vectors, n and L.

Example

```
 > n 
[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7

> L
[1]   2   2   4   4   4   4   4
```

For each value of n, I want to concatenate the integers between L and n when n>L, or retrieve the single value of n when L=n, or replace with value of 0 when L>n. I want to get a list (or other entity) with unequal vectors. Ideal output:

```
i
1 0
2 2
3 0
4 4
5 4 5
6 4 5 6
7 4 5 6 7
```

I have tried to use the colon operator (with the intention of replacing negative values later), e.g.

```
c((L):n)
```

But it comes with the error:

```
numerical expression has 205 elements: only the first used
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
f1 <- function(x,y) c(x, if(x < y) 0 else if(x == y) x else y:x)
Map(f1, n, L)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 0

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 0

#[[4]]
#[1] 4 4

#[[5]]
#[1] 5 4 5

#[[6]]
#[1] 6 4 5 6

#[[7]]
#[1] 7 4 5 6 7
```

If we need a `vector`

```
sapply(Map(f1, n, L), paste, collapse=" ")
#[1] "1 0"       "2 2"       "3 0"       "4 4"       "5 4 5"     "6 4 5 6"   "7 4 5 6 7"
```

---

Or if we just want to print it

```
for(i in seq_along(n))
 cat(c(n[i], if(n[i] < L[i]) 0 else if(n[i] == L[i]) n[i] else L[i]:n[i]), "\n")
#1 0 
#2 2 
#3 0 
#4 4 
#5 4 5 
#6 4 5 6 
#7 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Using `sapply` creates a list but the values are lumped as a character. I have used the `strsplit` function on spaces to obtain a list of separate number characters, e.g.  `"88" "89" "90"` instead of `"88 89 90"` but still cannot coerce them into numerical values for use in equations.

Comment: @M.Day  I didn't know what way you want the values.   But `Map(f1, n, L)` gives you a `list` of `numeric` vectors which can be used for your downstream calculations easily

Comment: Oh, indeed it does when extracted. Thanks @akrun. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A method using `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE` argument, giving a vector as a result

```
v1 <- ifelse(L > n, 0, ifelse(n == L, L, -1))
v1[v1 == -1] <- unique(unlist(Reduce(paste, x[v1==-1], y[v1==-1], accumulate = TRUE)))[-1]
#[1] "0"       "2"       "0"       "4"       "4 5"     "4 5 6"   "4 5 6 7"
```